# Android conditional permissions

Tags: android, security, permissions, android-support-library, feature-selection

I am building an android app that will be for sale through the market. The base application will need very minimal permissions.
What I want to do, is allow the base application customers to add libraries I'll have available as free upgrades. But those add-ons would need additional permissions and abilities. ( Like contacts, camera, live wallpaper, or home screen ).

My goal is to allow my customers buy my base application without requiring excessive permissions. But if they desire the extra features, they can simply install those libraries from the play market, and grant the permissions for those added libraries. But still allow all of these features to be detected, controlled and used from the base purchased app.

My fear is that no-one will buy my base application if it requires all the permissions of the optional features.

My question is...
Is it possible to do this? 
Are there other ways to set this up?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to package those libraries as separate apps, kind of what like Google does with Google Play Services.

These apps need not be visible in the application drawer, just don't declare any Launcher activities there.

You will then need to communicate with those apps using Intents to get your job done.